# Not able to double the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

I want to resize the array when the rehash function is called, by copying the values of initial dictionary into it and then at last redifining the newdictionary as dictionary

```
  void rehash ()
    {
        int newsize=2*Size;
        node **newdictionary;
        newdictionary= new node*[newsize];

        //Initialising the dictionary

        for (int i = 0;i < newsize;i++)
        {
            newdictionary[i]->name = "";
            newdictionary[i]->value = -1;
        }

        node **temp=dictionary;
        delete [] dictionary;
        dictionary=newdictionary;
        SIZE=newsize;
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            if(temp[i]->value!= -1)
                    insertvalue(temp[i]->name,temp[i]->value);
        }
        delete [] temp;
    };
```

Earlier I have defined insertvalue as:

```
      void insertvalue (string filedata, int code)
        {
            // tableindex is the position where I want to insert the value
            dictionary[tableindex]->name= filedata;
            dictionary[tableindex]->value=code;
        };
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually explain what problem(s) you're having, but your code has several issues:

```
void rehash ()
{
    int newsize=2*Size;
    node **newdictionary;
    newdictionary= new node*[newsize];
```

At this point, `newdictionary` is simply an array of uninitialized pointers.

```
    //Initialising the dictionary

    for (int i = 0;i < newsize;i++)
    {
        newdictionary[i]->name = "";
        newdictionary[i]->value = -1;
    }
```

So the loop above is trying to access the members of `node` objects that don't yet exist.

```
    node **temp=dictionary;
    delete [] dictionary;
```

These two lines don't make sense. `dictionary` and `temp` point to the same memory. So when you delete `dictinoary` you've deleted the memory that `temp` is pointing to.

```
    dictionary=newdictionary;
    SIZE=newsize;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(temp[i]->value!= -1)
                insertvalue(temp[i]->name,temp[i]->value);
    }
```

Even if you hadn't just deleted the memory out from under `temp`, you're now trying to access `temp` from 0 to the new size, not the old size. In other words, this would access `temp` beyond its bounds.

Those are the major problems that I've noticed in the code so far. You at least need to correct all of them before there's any hope of this working. You probably need to spend some time really stepping through your logic to ensure it makes sense in the end.